# Two Quick Questions - Can't Instert into Table & Can't Make a Select Statement Work

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a MySQL database and I've run into two problems.  The first is trying to add a row to an existing table using the SET system.  Here's the code and the error message I received:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO Instructors
-> SET FacId = 96
-> SET FirstName = 'Chris'
-> SET LastName = 'Explorer'
-> SET HomePhone = '555-1492';

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'SET FirstName = 'Chris' SET LastName = 'Explorer' SET 
HomePhone = '555-1492'' at line 3
```

The Second problem is a a search for all phone numbers that don't follow the preset pattern of ###-11##.  Here, again, is the code and the error I received:

```
mysql> SELECT FacId, FirstName, LastName, WorkPhone
-> FROM Instructors
-> WHERE WorkPhone != '555-11__';
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| FacId | FirstName | LastName   | WorkPhone |
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|     5 | Carlson   | Detroit    | 555-1196  |
|    12 |  Victoria | Windsor    | 555-5874  |
|    20 | George    | Herman     | 555-1147  |
|    31 | Justin    | Morgan     | 555-5874  |
|    33 | Thomas    | OHara      | 555-3698  |
|    34 |  Thett    | Poker      | 555-4865  |
|    35 | David     | Goliath    | 555-1178  |
|    37 | Dennis    | Locker     | 555-1169  |
|    43 | Sean      | Pent       | 555-4874  |
|    44 | Elizabeth | Tallman    | 555-5588  |
|    48 | Jane      | Fonder     | 555-1122  |
|    49 | Joe       | Footballer | 555-6611  |
|    83 | Allan     | German     | 555-5533  |
|    84 | Gregg     | Packer     | 555-5874  |
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong with these.  Any ideas?

Comment: This should be two questions.

Answer (score 1):

You use `SET` for `UPDATE` commands, not `INSERT` commands.  Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO Instructors (FacId, FirstName, LastName, HomePhone)
    VALUES (96,'Chris','Explorer','555-1492');
```

And for your second question (which should actually be a second question):

```
SELECT FacId, FirstName, LastName, WorkPhone
    FROM Instructors
    WHERE WorkPhone NOT LIKE '555-11__';
```

Comment: Thanks for the second answer.  That was exactly what I was doing wrong and I feel like an idiot for not realizing it.  *g*  Also, sorry for posting them together.  I'll make sure not to do so in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately, our instructor was very explicit that we were to use SET rather than the normal way of updating a file.  :-(

Comment: @George: Then use UPDATE, instead of INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to look up the syntax for INSERT, it goes like this:

   ```
   INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnName1, ColumnName2. .. )
       VALUES (Value1, Value2. . .)
   ```
2. You want the NOT LIKE operator, not the != operator.

Comment: Unfortunately, our teacher has expressly said that we MUST use the Set command for this particular update.

Comment: If you're trying to *update* (not *add*) data, you want to look up the syntax for **`UPDATE`**.  The `INSERT` command does not use the keyword `SET`.